# Animate a pie-chart in Keynote

Tags: keynote, animation

Suppose I want to compare two situations via two pie-charts. I know I can grow a pie-chart per part in an animation or on click. But I would like to be able to transition that pie-chart to new numbers and it grows or shrinks the appropriate parts automagically.

Clarification: I would like to animate between these two pie-charts:
[image]

Comment: Nice question, I'm going to keep an eye on this one

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do here. Are you asking for the ability to dynamically change the chart based on numbers you input during a presentation? Do you want to automatically re/create the animation based on numbers? Or are you just looking for the best way to create this animation for a given set of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach that's fairly quick and easy:

Create a Pie chart and input its values with the *Chart Data Editor*.

[image: image of Chart Data Editor]

With the chart object selected, open the *Slide Inspector* and set the transition for *Magic Move*

[image: image of Slide Inspector]

With the chart still selected, copy the chart object using the menu or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Create a new slide following your original and paste the chart object onto it.

Use the *Chart Data Editor* to change the values for your *pie slices* to reflect the new figures.

The chart will now morph from old to new when you advance the slides.

Comment: Not entirely what I wanted, but close enough :) Thanks!

Comment: I suspected you wanted an animation based on the individual parts. AFAIK, it's not possible with the Keynote tools. Best answer I could provide. I'm a simple slide advocate anyway: wow 'em with your [information](http://www.principiae.be/), not with wizzy special effects. Audience members are developing [*Zero tolerance for Bad Presentations*](http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/blog/X0018.php)

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, I _hate_ those slides that keep on animating. I find, however, that one (short) animation on a slide transition works well to keep students' attention :)

Comment: I'm not judging. At least not until I have sit through the preso. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I also wanted this effect , and am getting close to what I want by setting the first slide transition to 'Magic Move' with zero delay and Start Transition on 'Automatically', and then duplicating the first slide about 25 times, and incrementing each segment data value on each slide to get close to 'smooth clock winding' action on 'Play'

Comment: Nice expansion!